# Mac OS Sierra E-Mail Exchange

Tags: macos

I would like to setup Mac OS mail to use exchange mail server. However after adding my e-mail and password the next prompt wants me to enter local and remote proxy server address. Question is how do I get around this and simply get the prompt to enter the server address? For on iOS I could simply add the server address and connect to the exchange server to get access to mails, no proxy settings asked for.

Comment: You may want to give us the version of macOS and the version of the Exchange server. Also the steps you take to do this. Using the email account setup in Sierra connecting to an Exchange 2013 server it just asked for name, email and password and nothing else.

Comment: Its the latest version of sierra and exchange. I just click on create account-> exchange

Comment: Then you may have a network setup that involves proxies and mail and/or Exchange has detected that and wan'ts the info. If this is an Exchange server controlled by your work's IT department you are going to have to get with them, if it is not you will have to talk with whoever supports the Exchange server you are trying to use.